# How to get list of occurrence dates from iCalendar RRULE

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445

I have the iCalendar file with RRULE for occurrences. How to get the list of dates on which the event will be occurring as per given start date and RRULE in the iCal file.

In Java, I want to write a method which should take start date and RRULE and return me the list of occurrence dates. Please help with simple solution or directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Java library specifically for parsing RRULEs called [google-rfc-2445](https://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/).

The following link contains an example using the library where you supply a start date along with an RRULE and it prints out the dates.

http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

Comment: If you want to check out the source there is a clone on github: https://github.com/jcvanderwal/google-rfc-2445

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a chance to read [README](http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) because of **404 - The requested URL /svn/trunk/README.html was not found on this server**. If you have an example to show, please share it. I've found another solution [lib-recur](https://github.com/dmfs/lib-recur). lib-recur is shared via maven [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dmfs/lib-recur).